# Reputation needed to get SU in network profile

Tags: discussion, user-profiles

How much reputation is needed in Superuser to get it on the reputation chart in network profile? I had like 60 points before the linking bonus, and the reputation from stackoverflow starts from 11 in my network profile! I`m just curious about it.

Comment: I think you need at least 200 rep on a site before it appears, but I don't have a source yet... let me have a search.

Comment: Interesting, I believed that there was no rep requirement as such to have it on the network profile

Comment: @Sathya - sorry, my fault, having re-read I wasn't as clear as I thought: it will appear on the accounts list on any rep, but I think 200 is required before the it appears on the graph. (FYI: I can't find a source... but 200 is the minimum before sites are sorted in the SE sites drop-down the top-left, for example, so I think 200 is the "default" value for these things).

Comment: Indeed @DMA57361 it is 200rep. Just checked `/users` - 200 rep - graph is featured, 199 rep - no graph

Comment: @Sathya, ah good thinking, I can't find an MSO post to back it up but that looks pretty conclusive to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accounts appear on [your network profile accounts list](http://stackexchange.com/users/ec41edb2-00df-44f4-b25c-1e9c12d4d64b?tab=accounts) as soon as you associate them, but you require at least 200 rep before they appear on [your network profile reputation chart](http://stackexchange.com/users/ec41edb2-00df-44f4-b25c-1e9c12d4d64b?tab=reputation).

Once the account appears on the chart it will appear with a full history - the graph won't start at the point you pass 200rep, but passing the 200rep mark simply flags the account as important enough to be displayed.

Comment: What about Area51?

Comment: As far as I know A51 never appears in the reputation chart on the network profiles, presumably because it's not really a proper part of the wider network. You could ask on [MSO] if you want a more comprehensive answer, that's the best place A51 meta questions.